# Locate Cells With a Simple Criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data like:

[image]

I need to locate *(get row numbers)* for cells starting with the letter **A**.
My current approach is to use a "helper" column.  In **B1** I enter:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1)="A",1,"")
```

and in **B2** I enter:

```
=IF(LEFT(A2)="A",MAX($B$1:B1)+1,"")
```

and copy down.  This identifies the rows of interest.  Finally in **C1** I use:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(ROWS($1:1),$B$1:$B$23,0),"")
```

and copy down.

[image]

My goal is to eliminate the "helper" column.

The only two options I see are:

- use an autofilter
- use a VBA *UDF*

The autofilter approach is bad because the filter would have to be re-run whenever the data is refreshed.  The *UDF* approach bad because the sheet must work in a VBA-free environment.

Is there any kind of formula or array formula that can get the row numbers or am I stuck with the "helper"column ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this entered as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
{=SMALL(IF(LEFT($A$1:$A$23)="A",ROW($A$1:$A$23),9E+99),ROW())}
```

I presume your criteria is more complicated that this in your actual application, though. You can replace the `LEFT($A$1:$A$23)="A"` with any criteria you like and it'll still work.

Note that this will return `9E+99` if you copy it down for more rows than there are that start with "A". You could tweak it to return blank instead:

```
{=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(LEFT($A$1:$A$14)="A",ROW($A$1:$A$14),""),ROW()),"")}
```

Comment: PERFECT!! ...............this is exactly what I need.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I think the second formula is actually better. It'll return blanks if you copy it down too far.

Comment: I agree.................I will also be able to use your results in *INDEX()* formulas to retrieve data in other columns as well !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Put 0 in C1.
From C2: `=match(indirect("a"&c1+1&":a<last row>",true),"a*",0)+C1`
Notes: Match is not case sensitive. You need to manage errors after ask the matches are found.

Comment: Thanks! ..................I had to reverse the arguments to *MATCH(),*  but this worked **=MATCH("A*",INDIRECT("A"&C1+1&":A23",TRUE),0)+C1**  I guess each *MATCH()* starts where the previous one stopped.